# Haber en plural

Tags: gramática, ortografía, concordancia-gramatical

¿Se debe obligatoriamente conjugar el auxiliar `haber` en plural cuando el objeto es plural? Es decir, cuál de las siguientes oraciones es correcta:

`- En este viaje no ha habido peligros.`

`- En este viaje no han habido peligros.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta es la respuesta de la RAE:

> Cuando el verbo haber se emplea para denotar la mera presencia o existencia de personas o cosas, funciona como impersonal y, por lo tanto, se usa solamente en tercera persona del singular (que en el presente de indicativo adopta la forma especial hay: *Hay muchos niños en el parque*). En estos casos, el elemento nominal que acompaña al verbo no es el sujeto (los verbos impersonales carecen de sujeto), sino el complemento directo. En consecuencia, es erróneo poner el verbo en plural cuando el elemento nominal se refiere a varias personas o cosas, ya que la concordancia del verbo la determina el sujeto, nunca el complemento directo. Así, oraciones como *Habían muchas personas en la sala*, *Han habido algunas quejas* o *Hubieron problemas para entrar al concierto* son incorrectas; debe decirse *Había muchas personas en la sala*, *Ha habido algunas quejas*, *Hubo problemas para entrar al concierto*.

<sub>*Fuente [RAE](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/habia-muchas-personas-ha-habido-quejas-hubo-problemas#:%7E:text=As%C3%AD%2C%20oraciones%20como%20Hab%C3%ADan%20muchas,problemas%20para%20entrar%20al%20concierto.)*</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Yo digo que no es necesario, al menos no lo es en todos los contextos. Las palabras tomadas de *Las 500 dudas más frecuentes del español*, del Instituto Cervantes:

> **Se oyen a menudo frases como ‘Habían muchas personas’,
> ‘Hubieron fiestas’. ¿Son correctas?**

> **La norma culta no las considera aceptables**. Aparte de su uso como verbo auxiliar de los tiempos compuestos, el verbo haber se usa como impersonal para señalar la existencia de algo. Las formas correctas son:
>
> - Había muchas personas.
> - Hubo fiestas.
>
> El grupo nominal que aparece tras el verbo no es el sujeto, ya que el verbo es impersonal, sino su
> complemento directo. Por lo tanto, no debe establecerse concordancia [mentira, lo que quieren decir es que sí hay que establecer concordancia poniendo el verbo en singular], como muestran los siguientes
> ejemplos.
>
> - Hay un camino para llegar a la cima.
> - Hay varios caminos para llegar a la cima.
>
> En los ejemplos que aparecen en el enunciado de la pregunta, el verbo haber concuerda en plural con muchas personas y fiestas, que es el complemento directo, como hemos visto. Este uso no se considera válido en la norma culta, que propugna el uso no concordado [es decir, la concordancia sería en singular], a pesar de que la variante concordada parece estar en expansión en muchos países de América y en la zona oriental de España.
>
> - [supuestamente mal] Habían muchas personas en la calle.
> - [supuestamente bien] Había muchas personas en la calle.
> - [supuestamente mal] Nunca hubieron otros muebles en esta sala.
> - [supuestamente bien] Nunca hubo otros muebles en esta sala.
>
> La explicación de este error puede encontrarse, desde el punto de vista gramatical, en que se trata de un verbo impersonal transitivo que no admite la voz pasiva, y desde el punto de vista del significado, en que se iguala al régimen de otros verbos que indican existencia o presencia, como existir, ocurrir, tener lugar, etc., en los que lo acaecido constituye el sujeto de la oración (Existió una especie de cocodrilo gigante ~ Existieron varias especies de cocodrilo gigante).

Bla, bla, bla. Ellos mismos reconocen que cada vez es más común usar la variante en plural y, si bien no quiero que me reboten un *paper* por tener errores de ortografía (además de que veo que es muy improbable que presten atención a un detalle como ese), en la práctica conozco a muy poca gente que use la variante en singular. Por lo tanto, si corregís a alguien por una nimiedad como ésa lo único que vas a conseguir es que te tilden de *pedante*.